# DataBindXY with string-Values for xAxes gives 0 for x in Points Collections

Tags: c#, asp.net, charts, series

I fill a list with 12 strings as a timeline for a chose timespan

```
List<string> xValues = new List<string> 
{
  "Jan 2012", "Feb 2012", "Apr 2012", "Mai 2012", "Jun 2012", "Jul 2012", "Aug 2012",     "Sep 2012", "Okt 2012", "Nov 2012", "Dez 2012"
};

List<int> yValues = new List<int>();
foreach (string item in xValues )
{
    yValues.Add(0);
}
```

and fill a Series

```
mySeries.Points.DataBindXY(xValues, yValues);
```

Then i created another series which contains:

xvalue/yvalue:
    x = "Aug 2012", y = 2
    x = "Sep 2012", y = 1

and add both Series to Chart.Series Collection.

Now my problem. The points of both Series havent the Month-Strings as x-Value. They are all 0.

Debugger for Points shows me:

```
{X=0; Y=2}
{X=0; Y=1}
```

instead of what i want:

```
{X="Aug 2012"; Y=2}
{X="Sep 2012"; Y=1}
```

Here is a picture: http://www.imagebanana.com/view/jxyt4pxz/Unbenannt1.jpg

The 0´s dont lets start the graph at Aug 2012, he starts left at Jan 2012, because the series has no assignment between the xValues.

I hope u understand my problem. What is wrong? How can i get a assignemt between string-values at xAxes?

Comment: How are you adding the new points?

Comment: My Solution: Chart1.AlignDataPointsByAxisLabel();

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd488253.aspx